# Set theory proof for $\min C = \bigcap _{\alpha \in C} \alpha$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, ordinals, proof-explanation

Let $C$ be a set of ordinals

a) $\sup C$ is the least ordinal $\beta$ such that for all $\alpha\in C$, $a\leq \beta$.

b) If $C$ is transitive (and thereby ordinal), then $\sup C \notin C$ if an only if $\sup C$ is a limit ordinal or $\varnothing$.

c) $\min C = \bigcap _{\alpha \in C} \alpha$

Provide a proof.

I suppose the best starting point would be to show that $\sup C\notin C$ is not true when $C$ is a successor ordinal, correct? This I guess makes sense insofar as the successor ordinal of any given ordinal, by the nature of it being a successor, is included in the set $C$ correct? I'm sure there's a more eloquent way of putting it but that seems to make sense. (Is that adequate?)

For this (c) though I am not even sure what this means. What does this notation mean with $\alpha \in C$ as a subscript? The minimum of $C$ is equal to the intersection of $\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is in C... I'm almost sure I'm reading the notation wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Re: (c), it's the intersection, not the union. Remember that an ordinal is the set of all smaller ordinals - e.g. $5=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$. So for instance the minimum of $\{5, 128, \omega+7\}$ is $5$, and it's not hard to see that $5\cap 128\cap (\omega+7)$ is just $5$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is (a) a definition or something you're supposed to prove?  If the latter, what is your definition of sup?

Comment: @EricWofsey Supremum! :)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Partly. I guess I sort of don't really understand what you mean when you say $5\cap 128\cap (\omega +7)$ in that those elements aren't sets and don't intersect? Could you expand on that? And furthermore I don't understand why that intersection IS in fact 5 (i.e.; the minimum). But if that becomes clear that would certainly answer the question!!

Did my logic for (b) make sense to you? Could that be considered a complete proof?

Comment: I think there is a typo. When you wrote $C \not \in C$, you probably meant $\sup C \not \in C$, right?

Comment: @Stefan Good catch! Yes, I got it right the first time round and then messed up when I brought it up again! Whoops! Thank you

Comment: @lehtia Those elements **are** sets, and this is crucial to the exercise! In set theory, everything - including ordinals! - is a set. In particular, "$0$" is shorthand for the emptyset, "$1$" for $\{\emptyset\}$, "$2$" for $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}=\{0, 1\}$,  . . . and so on. If this is unfamiliar to you, you should look at the definition of ordinals in your text.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, yes of course. Well, what this proof seems to be getting at then is just that the intersection of any two ordinals is equal to the smaller of the two? Don't we know that the intersection between two ordinals is the largest set contained within both of them though?

Comment: @lehtia You're almost there - what you need to do is show that (1) every set of ordinals has a minimum element, and (2) that minimum element is indeed the intersection. This isn't too hard, but each step does take proof (although (2) is basically one line long).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

a) Recall that $\sup C = \bigcup C$. First of all prove that $\bigcup C$ is an ordinal.

Having verified that, suppose that $\gamma$ is such that $\alpha \le \gamma$ for all $\alpha \in C$, then consider two cases: If $C$ doesn't have a maximal element, then $\alpha \in \gamma$ for all $\alpha \in C$. Note that in this case $\sup C = \bigcup C \subseteq \gamma$ which yields $\sup C \le \gamma$. If $C$ does have a maximal element $\delta$, then verify that $\sup C = \delta$, which also implies $\sup C \le \gamma$.

b) If $C$ is a successor ordinal, it has a maximal element $\delta$. You verified in a) that $\delta = \sup C \in C$. If $C = \emptyset$, then clearly $\sup C \not \in C$. Finally let $C$ be a limit ordinal. I claim that $\sup C = C$ in this case, which yields $\sup C \not \in C$ - by regularity.

c) First of all prove that $\bigcap C  = \bigcap_{\alpha \in C} \alpha$ is an ordinal.

Now, if $\gamma < \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in C$, then $\gamma \in \bigcap C$ (note that $\bigcap C = \bigcap_{\alpha \in C}$) and hence $\bigcap C \le \min C$. On the other hand: If $\gamma < \bigcap C$, then $\gamma \in \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in C$ and thus $\gamma < \min C$. Therefore $\min C = \bigcap C$.